# What's another way of saying 'Now that I am approaching graduation'?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

What's another way of saying 'Now that I am approaching graduation' want to plan for.......?

I don't think the 'now that I am' sounds very smart.

Comment: Sure it does. The alternatives I was going to suggest all kept "Now that I am" and replaced the last half: "Now that I'm about to graduate" "Now that graduation is approaching" etc.

Comment: To improve that sentence, add the word *I* before the word *want*. The part in single quotes is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid requiring two *I* references ("*... I am ... [I] want ...*"), try this:

> With graduation approaching, I want to plan for ... .

Answer (score -1):

> "Now that I am approaching graduation, ***I*** want to plan for..."

The above sounds fine if it's what you mean.  The wording doesn't sound *un*-smart *per se*.  Syntactically, semantically, and grammatically, it's perfectly sound.  However, is it what you mean?  Is it really?

The first issue I question has to do with the word 'now'.  The way you say it, people will likely take it to mean that you want to plan *only now*, which is to construe that you didn't before.  However, graduations tend to be highly anticipated events, often a long time coming, predictable even, so wouldn't a smart person have wanted to plan before now?

The second issue has to do with the phrase 'want to plan'. It can sound rather wishy-washy.  You aren't saying that you are actually planning but only that you *want* to plan.  But if *to plan* is what you *want*, then why haven't you done?  Do you see how these words smack of noncommittal, as if you haven't braved the step to even begin to plan?

While neither of these conveyances are necessarily unintelligent, a very smart person *plans* rather than *wants to plan*, and that planning begins as a proaction long before approaching graduation rather than as a reaction *now* that it is.  What's more, a very smart person, even if they have been asleep at the wheel, doesn't betray themselves by copping to it, not unless they have some reason for wanting to appear weak or addled, which of course, you don't; otherwise, you wouldn't be asking how to sound smart.

Without knowing more context, what you plan to say after the ellipsis, it's difficult to definitively prescribe what you should say.  Nevertheless, I don't wish to leave you empty-handed.  I can't guarantee it's right for what you plan to say, but maybe simply say:

> With graduation approaching, I am planning for...